# How to change my code to run it more speedy?

Tags: excel, vba

I've one workbook with 170K rows, I will delete all rows when the result between cells is 0,
For those operation, normally I use the code below, but with 170K (the rows will be deleted are 90K) the code run very slowly.
Someone know another way more performance.
Thank

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 2 Step -1
   If (Cells(i, "K").Value + Cells(i, "L").Value) < 1 Then
       Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to delete the rows? Could you instead place the table in an array, filter out the rows that have a 0 value between cells, and then paste the new array on another tab in the worksheet? This I'm sure would be a lot quicker.

Comment: What do you mean by `the result between cells is 0`? In your code you are deleting rows where the sum of two adjacent cells (columns `K` and `L`) are less than 1...

Comment: @Alex P, my sheet have 12 columns, the last two contain some value, and if the sum of those two cells is 0 (<1 is the same?!?!?) the row isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank at all for your ideas but the really fast code is:
 use an array tu populate whit the correct date and replare all table of the end sort the table:

```
Sub Macro13(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim avvio As Date
Dim arresto As Date
Dim tempo As Date

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
avvio = Now()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim arng As Variant
    Dim arrdb As Variant
    Dim UR As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    Dim MyCol As Integer

    Set sh = Sheets("Rol_db")
    MyCol = 1
    sh.Select
    UR = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, MyCol).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arrdb(2 To UR, 1 To 12) As Variant
    For x = 2 To UR
    If Cells(x, 11) + Cells(x, 12) > 0 Then
        For y = 1 To 12
            arrdb(x, y) = Cells(x, y)
        Next y
    Else
        For y = 1 To 12
            arrdb(x, y) = ""
        Next y
    End If
Next x
    sh.Range("A2:L" & UR) = arrdb

arresto = Now()
tempo = arresto - avvio
Debug.Print "Delete empty rows " & tempo

Range("A2:L" & UR).Sort key1:=Range("A2:L" & UR), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
conclusioni:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

time for my sheet 170K 00:00:07.
as soon as I have a minute I feel a loop of the columns

Answer (score 2):

As long as your fine putting the data on a new tab, the code below will do everything you need in 1.5 seconds.

```
Sub ExtractRows()

Dim vDataTable As Variant
Dim vNewDataTable As Variant
Dim vHeaders As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Counter1 As Long, Counter2 As Long

With Worksheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
    vHeaders = .Range("A1:L1").Value2
    vDataTable = .Range("A2:L" & lastRow).Value2
End With

For i = 1 To UBound(vDataTable)
    If vDataTable(i, 11) + vDataTable(i, 12) > 0 Then
        Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
    End If
Next

ReDim vNewDataTable(1 To Counter1, 1 To 12)
For i = 1 To UBound(vDataTable)
    If vDataTable(i, 11) + vDataTable(i, 12) > 0 Then
        Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
        For j = 1 To 12
            vNewDataTable(Counter2, j) = vDataTable(i, j)
        Next j
    End If
Next

Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(1)

With Worksheets(2)
    .Range("A1:L1") = vHeaders
    .Range("A2:L" & Counter1 + 1) = vNewDataTable
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, my approach for your problem according to [rwilson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4567411/rwilson) idea.

I already tested it. It very very reduce executing time. Try it.

```
Sub deleteRow()

    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow, newRow As Long
    Dim sheetname As String
    Dim startTime As Double

    sheetname = "sheetname"

    With Sheets(sheetname)

        Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(.Name))

        'Firstly copy header
        newSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Value = .Rows(1).EntireRow.Value

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row

        newRow = 2

        For row = 2 To lastRow Step 1

            If (.Cells(row, "K").Value + .Cells(row, "L").Value) >= 1 Then

                newSheet.Rows(newRow).EntireRow.Value = .Rows(row).EntireRow.Value

                newRow = newRow + 1

            End If

        Next row

    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(sheetname).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    newSheet.Name = sheetname

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-VBA option you can try:

1. In column M compute the sum of columns K and L
2. Highlight column M and the click `Find and select > Find`
3. Type in `0` in the `Find what` box and also select `values` in the `Look in` box
4. Select `Find all` and in the box that shows the found items select all entires (click in the box and press `CTRL + A`)
5. On the ribbon select `Delete` and then `Delete sheet rows`
6. Now manually delete column M

I haven't tried this with 170k+ rows but maybe worth assessing performance versus the VBA loop.